# Coloring within distance from the boundary in R

Tags: r, geocoding

I work in R and am looking at a shapefile of North America. I'd like to color the map but only within 10 miles on each side of the US-Canada border and leave everything else uncolored. I'm a little stumped on how to do this and am hoping there's a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to have you in our community.

I do not know, if you are familiar with spatial objects and calculations in R. One of the packages you could use is `sf`, an alias for [simple features access for spatial objects](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html).  I've assembled you a little example using an equatorial border and some virtual countries near the equator to simulate your questioned setup. I use data.frames or in the case of `sf` spatial data frames for manipulation and calculation. The example is separated int two main topics:

**Step 1** in the example code, constructs the data set and shows a little bit how to:

1.1 to 1.5 prepare your data (input, example sets and functions)

1.6 switch between classic and spatial data.frame(s) and append spatial columns

1.7 change the coordinate systems using a spatial transformation

The resulting data set has 6 countries and an equatorial border line.

[image]

**Step 2** calculates the attributes to assign colors to your countries depending on the distance from the "equatorial border".

2.1 To assign the colors you could use a buffer with certain distance around your border of interests (in you question the 10 miles),

2.2 find out which of the countries are inside or touching these buffer,

2.3 assigning a color to the data.frame and plot the data sets.

[image]

**Example code**

```
require('sf')

# 1. Construction of a example data set  --------------------------------

# 1.1 Input parameter -------------------------
# Is needed to calculate the squares boundaries
COUNTRY.WIDTH  <- 1 # degree
COUNTRY.HEIGHT <- 1 # degree

# 1.2 Data set country centers  --------------------
# Assuming we have six virtual countries at
# the equator with a rectangular size 1x2 degrees

# GROUP1 is at the equator neighbored with a 
# displacement of the center latitude of 1 degrees N

# GROUP2 is in the North of GROUP 1 with a 
# displacement of the center latitude of 3 degrees N
# from the North equator 
COUNTRY.CENTERS <-
"GROUP  NAME  LON LAT   
 GROUP1 C1     -1   1 
 GROUP1 C2      0   1
 GROUP1 C3      1   1
 GROUP2 C4     -1   3    
 GROUP2 C5      0   3
 GROUP2 C6      1   3
" 

# 1.3 The border coded as a virtual equator -----------------
# The equator is coded as small subset of the original

# Equatorial Longitude --------------------
# beginning 2 degrees E and ending at 2 degrees W
EQ.LON <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.5)  

# Equatorial Latitude ----------
# Equatorial longitude always 0 degree
EQ.LAT <- rep(0, length(EQ.LON)) 

# 1.4 Function to construct the border of the countries as rectangle ----------
# We also need a function to construct the virtual country border 
# from the data set 
#' @param x - X coordinate of the center point
#' @param y - Y coordinate of the center point
#' @param w - width of the rectangular border
#' @param h - height of the rectangular border
#' @returns a simple feature polygon
SF.RECT.BORDER <- function(x, y, w, h) {
  
  # using the half of the cell size
  dw <- w/2  
  dh <- h
  
  # create the corner points
  nw.x <- x - dw; nw.y <- y + dh;
  ne.x <- x + dw; ne.y <- y + dh;
  se.x <- x + dw; se.y <- y - dh;
  sw.x <- x - dw; sw.y <- y - dh;
  
  # use vectors to arrange them in a matrix
  cx <- c(nw.x, ne.x, se.x, sw.x, nw.x);
  cy <- c(nw.y, ne.y, se.y, sw.y, nw.y);
  
  # create the coordinate matrix 
  coord <- matrix(c(cx, cy), ncol=2, nrow = 5 )
  
  # create the polygon 
  poly <- st_polygon(list(coord))
  
  # give back the results
  return(poly)
}

# 1.5 Function to construct a simple feature lines sting ----------------------
# From a set of x and y coordinate values
#' @param cx - vector of the X coordinate 
#' @param cy - vector of the Y coordinate
#' @param epsg - EPSG number of the coordinate system
#'               default is 4326 a.k.a. WGS84 based LON/LAT  
#' @returns a GEOMERY of arc polygon (OGC called LINESTRING) 
SF.VEC.TO.LINE <- function(cx , cy, epsg = 4326) {
  # Translate the simple vectors into a list
  # Code them into coordinates
  len.x <- length(cx)
  len.y <- length(cy)
  
  # Check if the length of the vecors are equal
  if (len.x !=len.y) {
    stop ("Lenght of vector cx and cy differ!")
  }
  coord <- matrix(c(cx, cy), ncol=2, nrow = len.x)
  line <- st_sfc(st_linestring(coord), crs =4326)  
} 
  
# 1.6 Store the data set in a R table first ----
#      append the border as geometry  
TAB <- read.table(text=COUNTRY.CENTERS, header =T)
TAB$BORDER <- apply(TAB[,c('LON','LAT')],1,
                   function(x)
                   SF.RECT.BORDER(x[1],x[2],
                                  COUNTRY.WIDTH,
                                  COUNTRY.HEIGHT))
head(TAB)
  

# 1.7 To get a simple feature GEOMETRY for your data sets ----

# A simple feature table of the virtual countries
CNT.GEOM <- st_sf(TAB,  crs = 4326)

# A simple feature for the equatorial border
EQ.GEOM  <- SF.VEC.TO.LINE(EQ.LON, EQ.LAT, epsg = 4326)

# 1.8 Get transform the geometry for "areal true" calculations in meter -----------

# Assuming all distances here and coordinate positions will
# be coded an euclidean coordinate system with the unit meter.
# If you want to calculate something in meter, you have to transform
# your data sets into an "areal true" coordinate system.
# Advise: the epsg 32630 codes the coordinate system
#         UTM30 with the Greenwich meridian (LON 0°) 
#         as center meridian.

EQ.UTM        <- st_transform(EQ.GEOM, crs = 32630)
CNT.GEOM$UTM  <- st_transform(CNT.GEOM$BORDER,  crs = 32630)

# 1.9 Plotting the resulting data set ----

# Calculate the extent of the graphics
BBOX    <- st_bbox(CNT.GEOM$UTM)      # Bounding box 
LIM.Y   <- c(-BBOX[4]/2, BBOX[4])     # Min / Max Y coordinate
LIM.X   <- c( BBOX[1], BBOX[3])       # Min / Max X coordinate
POS.X   <- mean(LIM.X)                # Center of X coordinates 
POS.Y   <- -BBOX[4]/25                # Position below the equator
POS.TXT <- st_centroid(CNT.GEOM$UTM)
POS.TXT.X <- st_coordinates(POS.TXT)[,1]
POS.TXT.Y <- st_coordinates(POS.TXT)[,2]

plot(CNT.GEOM$UTM, xlim=LIM.X, ylim=LIM.Y, col = '#aaddff')
plot(EQ.UTM, add = T, col = 'red', lwd =2)
text(POS.TXT.X, POS.TXT.Y, CNT.GEOM$NAME)
text( POS.X, POS.Y, 'EQUATOR', adj =c (0.5, 1))

# 2. Calculations -----------------------------------------------------------

# 2.1 Calculate a buffer around your equator 
BUFFER.DISTANCE <- 200000 # 200 km Buffer  
EQ.BUFFER <- st_buffer(EQ.UTM, dist = BUFFER.DISTANCE, crs = 32630)
   
# 2.2 Check if the country is inside or intersects the buffer
INTERSECTS <- st_intersects(CNT.GEOM$UTM, EQ.BUFFER, sparse = F)
WITHIN     <- st_within(CNT.GEOM$UTM, EQ.BUFFER, sparse = F)

# 2.3 Assign a color column with attributes
CNT.GEOM$COLOR <- 'white'
CNT.GEOM[   (WITHIN | INTERSECTS) ,'COLOR'] <- 'green'
CNT.GEOM[ ! (WITHIN | INTERSECTS) ,'COLOR'] <- 'red'

# 2.4 plot the dataset
plot(CNT.GEOM$UTM, xlim=LIM.X, ylim=LIM.Y, col = CNT.GEOM$COLOR )
plot(EQ.UTM, add = T, col = 'red', lwd =2)
text(POS.TXT.X, POS.TXT.Y, CNT.GEOM$NAME)
text( POS.X, POS.Y, 'EQUATOR', adj =c (0.5, 1))
plot(EQ.BUFFER, add=T, col = '#dddddda0')
text( POS.X, POS.Y+5*POS.Y, 'BUFFER', adj =c (0.5, 1))

# EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated. To follow up, the code checks whether a polygon is inside the buffer and assigns a color based on the result. But if I just want to color inside the buffer, then I can directly assign color to the buffer?

Comment: You could then cut the country polygons and by the buffer and color the resulting polygons.